# Вызов Linux из загрузчика Windows(BCD)

Tags: linux

На USB-диске первый раздел с Windows 8, второй с Linux. Загрузчик Linux установлен во второй раздел. Как сделать, чтобы загрузчик Windows вызывал Linux из 2-го раздела?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/785013/178988

Answer (score 1):

Согласен с 3JIoi_Hy6. Самым удобным способом будет сделать основной загрузочный раздел с Linux, а уже в него добавить разделы с Win. Сложностей с добавлением сторонней ос в загрузчиках Linux нет. Будь это хоть Lilo или Grub 1.99\2.

Answer (score 0):

Я не уверен, но можно попробовать узнать путь и параметр загрузки Линукса (у меня это Настройка компьютера-Загрузка-Настройка загрузки, а дальше выбираем "Изменить пункт меню загрузки"), и скопировать в boot.ini. Другой вариант -- сделать загрузку с раздела Линукса, а там можно легко добавить Виндовс в меню загрузки. Можно еще [тут](http://linuxgazette.net/issue36/larriera.html) почитать, а ещё лучше [тут](http://www.google.com.ua/search?aq=0&oq=boot.&gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=boot.ini#pq=boot.ini&hl=ru&cp=12&gs_id=n&xhr=t&q=boot.ini+linux&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=boot.ini+lin&aq=0&aqi=g1&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=cf.osb&fp=2bbe7232f4c94b91&biw=1916&bih=889)!

Comment: У меня не boot.ini и не Windows XP, а BCD и Windows 8.

Comment: Не заметил... А вообще, на Хешкоде Вам уже ответили, что так сделать нельзя. Действительно, сначала надо ставить Линукс, а затем уже Окошки. Ну, можно ещё загрузиться с какого-нибудь LiveCD и сделать раздел с Линуксом основным.