# Запуск второй ОС

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ос, dual-boot

Такая ситуация: на ноутбуке я поставил SSD вместо жесткого диска, на SSD установил Ubuntu. Жесткий подключил вместо дисковода, и на него поставил Windows. Я думал можно будет при запуске менять в биосе приоритет запуска и запускать то одну, то другую ОС при необходимости. Но получается так, что как бы я не баловался с приоритетами биоса, запускается все равно та ОС, которая стоит сейчас там, где изначально стоит жесткий диск. Можно все таки как-то менять их при запуске или мне надо постоянно переставлять SSD и HDD местами? У меня был момент, когда и там и там у меня стояла ubuntu и мне предлагалось при запуске, какую из них надо запускать, вот я и подумал, что так можно.

Comment: А если сделать `sudo update-grub`, загрузочное меню Ubuntu не обнаруживает Windows?

Comment: ноут грузится в легаси а не в UEFI, я так понимаю? если в UEFI, установщики прописали в настройках загрузку с жесткого диска, а внешний м.б. только легси?

Comment: Все, с `sudo update-grub` увидел Windows. @D-side 
 Спасибо)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Windows не видно в Grub 2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/341080/windows-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b2-grub-2)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, не дубликат, потому что тут возможно ещё одно решение решение - добавить grub в загрузчик винды.

Answer (score 2):

**Когда вы устанавливали Ubuntu, диск с Windows, видимо, не был подключен**, и на этапе настройки GRUB Windows просто не было, поэтому в меню загрузки она не попала.

Можно настроить GRUB повторно, запустив `update-grub` от рута (`sudo update-grub`).

---

GRUB не занимается сканированием системы на наличие на дисках ОС при каждой загрузке, обычно это делается один раз, в процессе установки GRUB (который, в свою очередь, происходит в процессе установки Ubuntu).

В процессе настройки "ОС-зонд" (OS prober), сканирует диски системы на предмет ОС, в которые GRUB умеет загружаться, результаты сканирования сохраняются в понятном GRUB виде на диск и образуют меню загрузки.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно просто прописать один загрузчик в другой и при загрузке системы выбирать, какую систему ты хочешь запустить.

Как добавить windows в grub написали в соседнем ответе, но можно поступить и наоборот - добавить grub в загрузчик windows. Это умеет делать программа [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/), правда, она бесплатна только для некоммерческого использования.

У меня на компьютере настроено именно с её помощью (правда, у меня классический bios, а не uefi). Кстати, я настроил и сам grub, т. е. сейчас я могу запускать любой загрузчик из любого.