# Что сделать, чтобы отображалось окно выбора ОС?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, администрирование, bios

На компьютере на разных физических дисках установлена `Ubuntu` и `Windows 10`.
Сейчас для переключения ОС приходится заходить в `boot` меню `bios`.

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы при запуске компьютера, отображалось бы окно выбора операционной системы?**

Comment: использовать grub или его аналоги?

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-boot

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/784681/178988 - дубликат?

Comment: Как вариант: у многих есть boot menu на стартовом экране, где по F2/Del вызывается биос, а по F7-F12, у всех по-разному, есть выбор устройства загрузки.

Comment: @Qwertiy, нет не дубликат. Через биос, при изменении приоритета загрузки у дисков у меня всё нормально получается. Меня просто бесит, что постоянно приходится в биос заходить, при запуске. Хочется что при самом запуске, сразу, открывалось меню выбор операционной системы, как когда две винды установлены в системе

Comment: @KoVadim, похоже на то что нужно, спасибо